# Jenkins cannot access Git repository on Azure Ubuntu VM

Tags: git, azure, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I get the following error when I try to connect to my git repository.

[image]

This is my credential that i'm using. Any pointers to what I'm doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to use the latest version of the Git SCM plugin, in order to avoid [issue like JENKINS-20879](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20879).
That issue also illustrates how to register a private key protected by a passphrase. In your case, make sure you don't have a passphrase (or your key would not be properly registered in Jenkins, [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18193633/6309))

Make sure to test it outside of Jenkins

```
ssh -Tv -i /path/to/id_rsa git@ip.address
```